# Gitlab: bookmark repo functionality - how and what?

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab has little bookmark icons next to each repo (see screenshot below). However, clicking the icon (or anywhere in the row for that repo) takes you to the repo - the whole thing is a link, so clicking the icon doesn't bookmark the repo. I also can't find a way to bookmark a repo via its settings.

Furthermore, what does the bookmark functionality do? I was imagining that it pins it to the top of your list, or makes it available on a bookmarks page, both of which would be really useful for me ... but I'm not actually sure.

Weirdly enough, google really isn't helping me out with this one. Does anyone have some info about this functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a bit of a UX convention violation - you're right that icon is absolutely a bookmark and typically used for bookmarking something. However in this case it just signifies that row is a Project as opposed to a Group. If that icon is a bookmark, it's a Project. If that icon is a folder, it's a Group.

If you want to favorite Projects, you should star them by clicking on the Star icon in the upper right of the Project home screen, then when you click on "Projects" you can click on "Starred Projects" and see all your projects you've currently starred. You can also filter activity based on starred projects.

Comment: Ohhh ... yeah, that UX is not what I thought! It's also called a bookmark in the HTML/CSS if you inspect it - and since it's currently showing as an outline icon, I was expecting that it would become solid/filled in if actually bookmarked.  Anyway, will do what you suggest re: starring projects!